# Firebase normal query in a transaction

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, transactions

Some questions regarding Transaction in Firebase.

Transaction documentation says read before write. Let's say if I `t.get()` 2 documents in a `db.runTransaction(t)` in the beginning. Then mid-way in the runTransaction code block, I `t.update()` both documents. Does it mean that if there are any changes in the 2 documents beyond the `t.update()`, the runTransaction will retry?

Also, if I do a normal document `get()` within the transaction code block, will changes in the document after the `get()` within the transaction cause the transaction to retry?

```
db.runTransaction(async t => {
   const snapshot1 = await t.get(db.collection('col1').doc('doc1'));
   const snapshot2 = await t.get(db.collection('col2').doc('doc2'));
   const snapshot3 = await db.collection('col3').doc('doc3').get();

   // changes in col1.doc1 or col2.doc2 will trigger retry
   // QUESTION: Will changes in col3.doc3 trigger a retry?
   doSomething(snapshot1);
   doSomething(snapshot2);

   await Promise.all([
       t.update(snapshot1.ref, { field1: 'a' }),
       t.update(snapshot2.ref, { field1: 'b' })
   ]);
   // QUESTION: will changes in col1.doc1 or col2.doc2 externally beyond here trigger a retry

   doSomething(snapshot3);
});
```

Appreciate all your expert views/insights. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> Does it mean that if there are any changes in the 2 documents beyond
> (before) the `t.update()`, the Transaction will retry?

Yes, as explained in the doc: "In the case of a concurrent edit, Cloud Firestore runs the entire transaction again"

> Also, if I do a normal document get() within the transaction code
> block, will changes in the document after the get() within the
> transaction cause the transaction to retry?

You should not fetch a document with a "normal" `get()` but use the transaction's `get()` method (i.e. `t.get()`). With a normal `get()` the document will not be "included" in the transaction.

---

In addition, note that you don't need to do:

```
await Promise.all([
    t.update(snapshot1.ref, { field1: 'a' }),
    t.update(snapshot2.ref, { field1: 'b' })
]);
```

because [`t.update()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Transaction#update) is **not** asynchronous. It does not return a Promise but the Transaction instance itself, and can be used for chaining method calls like:

```
t.update(snapshot1.ref, { field1: 'a' }).update(snapshot2.ref, { field1: 'b' })
```

Note that it's similar for [`set()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Transaction#set) and [`delete()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Transaction#delete).